# View in SP Online lists that only shows latest items (by day)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to create a rather simple view in a SharePoint Online list, but I'm having trouble with the expressions and logic. The list is a project report in which the info from all received project requests in an extended shift is entered daily.

I want to have a view that only shows projects entered during the last day, i.e. the latest report. I could do [Today] - 1 in a filtered view, but that breaks on Sundays/Mondays, and if the user is accessing the list on the same night of a shift (they'd always see yesterday's report), I think the best way is to show elements from the most recent day, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

If SharePoint allows for a more complicated logic in a filtered view, I haven't been able to find information on the right syntaxis, because nothing I've seen online (like using logic with WEEKDAY and similar functions) and applied to a filtered view seems to work.

Any help is much appreciated. I'm sure this can be accomplished and that I'm missing something basic (fairly new to the SP world).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For yesterday's records, try the below

```
[Created]> [Today]-2 and [Created]<[Today]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't quite do what I want. Yesterday's records would work with simply [Today] - 1, but what happens if it's Sunday or Monday, I'd be looking at Saturday's or Sunday's records, which be an empty view. I think the best approach is to group them based on the latest date,  i.e. determine what's the day of that latest created date and show records from that day only. The thing is I don't know how to actually implement that logic in SharePoint.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. Yes, what you're already planning, that is, Grouping the records by [Created] date should work. What logic are you referring to? Group by is available when you're creating/editing a view

Comment: I can group by the created date, but I still see all records, from every day. Is there a way to show only the newest group?

Comment: You can try `<GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="1">` which will show the first group on the first page. The remaining groups will show up in the subsequent pages. You may need to edit the view's CAML in SP Designer.